# Why does IEEE 754 categorize convertFromInt and convertToIntegerXXX as arithmetic operations and not conversion operations?

Tags: floating-point, type-conversion, ieee-754, c11

IEEE Std 754-2019:

> 5.4.1 Arithmetic operations
>
> ― formatOf-convertFromInt(int)
>
> ― intFormatOf-convertToIntegerXXX(source)

Question: why `convertFromInt` and `convertToIntegerXXX` are categorized as *arithmetic operations* and not *conversion operations*?

The reason forthe question:

C11 (emphasis added):

> 5.2.4.2.2 Characteristics of floating types <float.h>
>
> 3    A *quiet NaN* propagates through almost every _arithmetic operation *without raising a floating-point exception*; a signaling NaN generally raises a floating-point exception when occurring as an arithmetic operand.

According to IEEE 754 (both 2008 and 2019) `convertFromInt` and `convertToIntegerXXX` are categorized as *arithmetic operations* and not *conversion operations*.

According to C11 (emphasis added):

> F.4 Floating to integer conversion
>
> 1    ... Otherwise, if the floating value is infinite or *NaN* or if the integral part of the floating value exceeds the range of the integer type, then the *‘‘invalid’’ floating-point exception is raised* and the resulting value is unspecified. ...

Here *NaN* is not specialized, hence, we conclude that *NaN* here is *any NaN*.

Also C11 (emphasis added):

> F.3 Operators and functions
>
> The lrint and llrint functions in <math.h> provide the IEC 60559 *conversions* ... The lrint and llrint functions can be used to implement IEC 60559 *conversions from floating to other integer formats*.

However, according to IEEE 754 (both 2008 and 2019) `convertFromInt` and `convertToIntegerXXX` are categorized as *arithmetic operations* and not *conversion operations*.

Overall: I am confused. I see the contradiction between C11 and IEEE 754.

Code sample:

```
l = (long)NAN; // shall lead to raising of FE_INVALID ??
```

Here:

1. IEEE 754 says: `convertToIntegerXXX` is categorized as *arithmetic operations* AND C11 says: *quiet NaN propagates through almost every arithmetic operation without raising a floating-point exception*.
2. C11 says: *if the floating value is infinite or NaN or if the integral part of the floating value exceeds the range of the integer type, then the ‘‘invalid’’ floating-point exception is raised*`.

Core question: Shall `l = (long)NAN` lead to raising of `FE_INVALID`?

Extra question: IEEE 754: are `convertFromInt` and `convertToIntegerXXX` incorrectly categorized as *arithmetic operations* instead of being categorized as *conversion operations*?

It seems that indeed IEEE 754 incorrectly categorizes them. For `l = (long)NAN` clang 13.0.0 for x86_64 generates `cvttss2si`, which [raises invalid floating-point exception](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvttss2si). Note: gcc 11.2 still ignores `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS`.

Comment: "categorized" seems a bit strong here. As far as I can tell, the issue is merely that `convertFromInt` and `convertToInteger*` appear under a non-totally-accurate subheading "5.4.1 Arithmetic operations", I'd guess for reasons of convenience and/or history. But it seems inconsequential: @pmor - are you aware of places where this "categorization" is used, and where it would matter if `convertFromInt` were considered an arithmetic operation versus a conversion operation?